# How to read a CSV file in Pandas with quote characters and comma?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset like this:

```
ISIN,"MIC","Datum","Open","Hoog","Laag","Close","Number of Shares","Number of Trades","Turnover","Valuta"
NL0011821202,"Euronext Amsterdam Brussels","04/09/2017","14.82","14.95","14.785","14.855","7482805","6970","111345512.83","EUR"
NL0011821202,"Euronext Amsterdam Brussels","05/09/2017","14.91","14.92","14.585","14.655","15240971","12549","224265257.14","EUR"
NL0011821202,"Euronext Amsterdam Brussels","07/09/2017","14.69","14.74","14.535","14.595","15544695","15817","227478163.74","EUR"
```

However I can't read the file in correctly with pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
I've tried all kinds of combinations like:

```
 sep='"',
 delimiter=","
```

But with no luck at all!
I want the first line to be the columns and the quote characters and comma to be removed.

How do I go about this efficiently?

Comment: For me working very nice `pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`, is possible share real sample file with 3 rows, e.g. by dropbox, gdocs or similar?

Comment: Could try `pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', quotechar='"')` ?

Comment: Btw, tested in `pandas 0.23.4`

Comment: @ChrisA Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is there is sometimes double `"`, solution is change separator for match zero or more `"` before and after `,`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ING_DAILY - ING_DAILY.csv',  sep='["]*,["]*', engine='python')
```

Then is necessary remove `"` from columns names and from first and last columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
df.iloc[:, [0,-1]] = df.iloc[:, [0,-1]].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
print (df.head(3))

           ISIN                          MIC       Datum   Open    Hoog  \
0  NL0011821202  Euronext Amsterdam Brussels  04/09/2017  14.82  14.950   
1  NL0011821202  Euronext Amsterdam Brussels  05/09/2017  14.91  14.920   
2  NL0011821202  Euronext Amsterdam Brussels  06/09/2017  14.69  14.725   

     Laag   Close  Number of Shares  Number of Trades      Turnover Valuta  
0  14.785  14.855           7482805              6970  1.113455e+08    EUR  
1  14.585  14.655          15240971             12549  2.242653e+08    EUR  
2  14.570  14.615          14851426             15303  2.175316e+08    EUR
```

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work with `low_memory=True`, because that parameter uses C, while `sep='["]*,["]*'` only uses python engine