# How to read CSV file ignoring commas between quotes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've recently started to use Pandas.

Here's my csv file.

```
column1,column2,column3
a, b, c
a, b, "c, d"
```

I want `"c, d"` to be in column3 like here:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| a | b | c, d |

But using `data = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv', sep=',', quotechar='"', encoding='utf-8')` I get this table instead:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| a, b, "c, d" | None | None |

I've tried to change values of some of parameters in `read_csv`. And also regular expression from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166302/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-pandas-with-quote-characters-and-comma).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try

```py
data = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv', sep=',', quotechar='"',
                   skipinitialspace=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

which tells pandas to ignore the space that comes after the comma, otherwise it can't recognize the quote.

**EDIT**: Apparently this does not work for the author of the question

Therefore, this is a script that produces the wanted result.
I have python 3.8.9, pandas 1.2.3.

`itworks.py`

```py
import pandas as pd

with open("testfile.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("""column1,column2,column3
a, b, c
a, c, "c, d"
""")

data = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv", sep=",", quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True, encoding="utf-8")
print(data)
```

```
$ python itworks.py
  column1 column2 column3
0       a       b       c
1       a       c    c, d
$
```

Try to reproduce this minimal example.

Comment: I've tried this before asking ) It didn't help.

Comment: @Ferapont I tried this on my computer, with exactly your input and the exact same command I showed in the answer, and I get exactly the result you want.

Comment: This script works on my PC too. But when I edit csv in excel,  save it and after that call `pd.read_csv("testfile.csv", ...)` I get the same wrong result. I'm now trying to understand why it works in such way.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517311/reading-a-csv-file-into-pandas-dataframe-with-quotation-in-some-entries) is the explanation.

Comment: Well, I guess you could also try not to use Microsoft Excel. There are alternatives which are more programming-friendly, and more powerful (but less user-friendly).